# Repetitive Peak Reverse Current of Diode

Tags: diodes, schottky

I am trying to select an appropriate diode for the gate circuit of a power MOSFET.  I am considering the [STMicro STPS140Z](https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/stps140z.html) Schottky diode for this application; however as I am reading the datasheet there is a specification for "Repetitive Peak Reverse Current".  I assume this means that I cannot apply a reverse current greater than what is specified (pulse width of 2us over a 1kHz frequency?  Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: This probably won't make much sense unless you include an example of the circuit (they do have a tool to draw circuits and edit the question).

Answer (score 2):

\$V_{RRM}=40V~,~ I_{RRM}=0.5A ~~2us\$ on @ 1kHz ABS MAX

This is a zener 20 W-pk *2/500us = 80 mW avg power-limiting condition outside the normal operation.  The reverse current bandgap cannot handle the same Pavg as the forward bandgap.

In LEDs and BJT-BE junctions the ratio of forward/reverse current ratio is similar .  e.g. some 30mA LEDs are -5V 10uA but actual limit for voltage before burnout will be higher.